# Responsive table, trying to get header *above* the column

Tags: html, css

we have a table like below. I am trying to make this responsive using some tricks found [here](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/).

The result now is that I see the following on an iPhone:

```
header1
header2
etc
col1
col2
etc
```

When I was hoping for

```
header1
col1
header2
col2
etc
```

**My question:** How can I show my header first, followed by all rows (from column, then header + data from column 2, then header + data from column 3, etc

help appreciated

---

Example HTML

```
<h2>table</h2>
<table class="ox_table">
<thead>
<tr><th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th><th>header4</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>col1</td>
<td>col2</td>
<td>col3</td>
<td>col4</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Example CSS

```
/* Make responsive */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 table.ox_table, table.ox_table thead, table.ox_table td, table.ox_table tr, table.ox_table tbody, table.ox_table th { display: block;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to edit your HTML, just add your data to a non-table structure and hide it, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/r44mof0t/

```css
div.ox_table {
  display: none;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  table.ox_table {
    display: none;
  }
  div.ox_table {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>table</h2>

<table class="ox_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
      <td>col4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="ox_table">
  <h4>header1</h4>
  <p>col1</p>
  <h4>header2</h4>
  <p>col2</p>
  <h4>header3</h4>
  <p>col3</p>
  <h4>header4</h4>
  <p>col4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but we want to show the table. The question is how we can preserve the headers (beloning to column)

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning, like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/r44mof0t/1/

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  table.ox_table,
  table.ox_table thead,
  table.ox_table tbody,
  table.ox_table tr,
  table.ox_table td,
  table.ox_table th {
    display: block;
  }
  table.ox_table {
    position: relative;
  }
  table.ox_table thead,
  table.ox_table tbody {
    line-height: 250%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
  }
  table.ox_table tbody {
    top: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>table</h2>

<table class="ox_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>header1</th>
      <th>header2</th>
      <th>header3</th>
      <th>header4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
      <td>col3</td>
      <td>col4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```